# Calling c++ dll from c#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

```
**unmanaged class**
```

this is the unmanaged class declaration

```
#ifdef EXPORT_CLASS
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
public class DLL_EXPORT cppclass
{
private:
string x;
public:
cppclass();
~cppclass();
string native();
};


**UNMANAGED CLASS DEFINITION**
```

this is the unmanaged class definition

```
 cppclass::cppclass()
{
x="hello";
};
cppclass::~cppclass()
{
};
string cppclass::native()
{
return x;
};

**MANAGED CLASS**
```

this is the managed class declaration

```
public __gc class Mclass
{
//private:
public:
cppclass * obj;
public:
Mclass();
~Mclass();
string native();
```

};

```
**MANAGED CLASS DEFINITION**
```

//this is the managed class definition

```
#include"managed.h"
Mclass::Mclass()
{
    obj=new cppclass();
};
Mclass::~Mclass()
{
    delete obj;
};
string Mclass::native() 
{
return  obj->native();
};
```

All these four files are in a project which is made into a dll.Now how to use it in a c# project

Comment: The snippet is very incomplete.  The Mclass must be declared `public ref class` so it is visible outside of the assembly.  And you *must* implement a finalizer so you don't leak memory when the client code doesn't call Dispose().  And your native() method should check if *obj* wasn't deleted.

Comment: @HansPassant:your help is highly appreciated....will try to post complete snippets in future for clarity....

Comment: The point is to do it *now*, not next time.

Comment: @HansPassant:sorry for taking too long...edited the code

Comment: have you check swig before? http://www.swig.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole thing is a disaster.  That isn't C++/CLI code, it's the old Managed Extensions for C++ which are broken.  Also, exporting native classes from DLLs is a really bad idea.  Statically link your native code with the managed class definition, creating a single DLL.

Comment: sorry for the confusion....the native code along with the managed class definition are in a project which together creates a dll

Comment: @Manu: Ok, that's good.  You should nuke all the `EXPORT_CLASS` and `__declspec(dllexport)` stuff then, it's just begging for someone to turn it on and cause trouble.

Answer (score 5):

Add a reference to the DLL in your C# project and simply use it like any .NET type.
Probably you don't find any exported types in the DLL, because these have to be public.

Edit: BTW. i hope you're talking about C++/CLI, not Managed C++ which was prior to C++/CLI.

Comment: Classes don't have to be in a namespace though AFAIK

Comment: @Simon yup i am talking about C++/CLI.Can you please elaborate a little with an example

Comment: @ManuDilipShah - You should be able to simply add the reference to the compiled C++/CLI file to your project.  You wanting example makes no sense.  If you have a new question, start a new question, post a better sample application when you do.